# Draw a box in HTML, Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

My application is similar to moonpig or hallmark in the customised card style operation. In the administrative section I need the admin to be able to load in an image of a card and draw a box on this card to define the x, y, width and height of the customisation area and in doing so, storing this x, y, width and height variables. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking to crop the image. If this is the case, you can have a look at the jQuery Image Cropping plugin. http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Comment: This is perfect. Cheers dude!

Comment: @Daniel Glad I was able to help. :) And don't forget to mark it as answer.